# registerHelper - issue starting gruntjs

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, npm

Hey guys a buddy of my is wanting me to checkout his angular-swing project and for some reason I am unable to start the server.

Here is what I am getting:

```
Running "serve" task
Loading "clean.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'registerHelper'

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Warning: Object #<Object> has no method 'helper' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Have you run `bower update` and `npm update` while standing in the root folder of the project?

Comment: @simpe that did the trick, could you leave an awnser nd to why that worked?

Comment: Glad it solved your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a `bower update` and a `npm update` while standing in the root folder of the project. This will update all bower and npm modules and install those that are missing from your local folders. The folder that contains these modules are usually stored in e.g. `.gitignore` due to their size.

This is usually my first go-to fix when working with multiple people on the same project.